# Create a tkinter button whose command can accept arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a  tkinter button, that when pressed should trigger creation of a custom class (class "manual_entry").

The custom class in its **init**() has creation of tkinter toplevel window. Snippet of code for clarify:

```
def __init__(self,main,myobject):
   manual=tk.Toplevel()
   something something
```

This toplevel windows does something to myobject, which is another class irrelevant to question.

When I call this class, for example:

```
variable=manual_entry(main,myobject)
```

it works perfectly.  But what I specifically want is that this class be created upon a button prompt from tkinter main window. Snipped of code:

```
def create_ent(main,myobject):
    variable=manual_entry(main,myobject)

tk.Button(master=main,text="!",command=create_ent(main,museobj).grid()
```

Now what I should have is a tkinter window containing only button "!" which when I press, I get my own toplevel window. But instead, I simply get toplevel window ("manual") without even touching "!" button.

Upon further experimentation, if I were to do this

```
def test(a):
   print(a)
   return()
a="test"
tk.Button(master=main,text="!",command=beg(a)).grid()
main.mainloop()
```

What I get is automatically printed "test", without any prompt for button pressing.

What I want, in a nutshell, is a way to pass function that takes arguments as a tkinter command.

Comment: Use `lambda`: `command=lambda: create_ent(main,museobj)`.

Comment: or look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

Comment: @acw1668 that works and thanks, I'll implement that!
But why does command need to be passed as lambda function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For passing in arguments, you will have to use `lambda` or `functools.partial`. I recommend using `lambda` as there is no extra imports.

```
tk.Button(master=main,text="!",command=lambda: create_ent(main,museobj)).grid()
tk.Button(master=main,text="!",command=lambda: beg(a)).grid()
```

Or using `partial` would be like:

```
from functools import partial

tk.Button(master=main,text="!",command=partial(create_ent,main,museobj)).grid()
tk.Button(master=main,text="!",command=partial(beg,a)).grid()
```

[Click here to read more about `functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

---

Why do we have to use these `lambda` or `partial`?

It is just because when you use `()` with a function, python calls the function directly and suddenly, which clearly defies the purpose of having a button. So you use `lambda` or `partial` which create another function that stores the given function or expression(in case of `lambda`) which will be called by `tkinter` *only* when the button is pressed.

Comment: Yeay finally someone recognised that `functools.partial` exists.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why exactly do functions need to be passed as lambda for passing in arguments?

Comment: @ivan199415 I've updated the answer with that question too.